# What are these connectors?

Tags: sram

And how can I connect to them with my own stylish red hoses?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are SRAM inline hydraulic hose connectors, [an article on Bikerumor](https://bikerumor.com/2013/04/15/sram-hydro-r-hydraulic-road-rim-disc-brakes-unveiled-details-first-rides/) mentions these are supposed to be OEM only:

> We mentioned that the new Connectamajig will be offered for use with
>   this, and it’s aimed at the OEM manufacturers to ease assembly line
>   efforts. SRAM’s product managers were careful to point out that it’s
>   not really designed to be a quick disconnect for travel frames, it’s
>   primarily to make installation easier.

[image]

If you look at photo above, you can see the male part, so I'd look around for it. Also, if you are building a brand new Specialized out of the box, I'd try to connect their customer support or wherever you purchased the bike from for assembly advice.